# Carrying the Torah around

Tags: shabbat, song-poetry, torah-service

When the Torah is taken out and is being carried around songs are being sung. I would like to know which songs exist for this part of the service and where I could find traditional tunes for those songs.

Comment: Did you look in a siddur?

Comment: @ezra yes indeed, but I’m curious if others use different songs. I once heard Shlosha Devarim and Ki MiTzion also. P.s. I noticed you said ‘Veyehi Binsoa Ha’Aron’ but isn’t that song used when carrying out the Torah of the Ark? I’m looking for songs when it is carried around at the moment people touch it with the tzittzit, books, and taken to the bimah.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is one such song](https://youtu.be/OsnJpv2BU6g?t=99), with text shown. The words are taken from the prayers said as the Torah is brought to the Bimah.

Comment: Also "Vayehi Binsoa HaAron"

Comment: Also the oldest of them all: "Al Hakol"

Comment: @DoubleAA, I'm one of only a few folks in my schul who even say it.

Comment: @ezra, the sefer is invariably not removed until after ויהי בנסע is sung. I don't recite בריך שמיה (surprise, surprise) so they come out immediately after ברוך שנתן וכי׳

Comment: The Torah should come out before brich shemei according to many poskim anyhow